# Can I transfer digital movies I've purchased onto a disc?

Tags: ps4, psn

If I buy a movie on my PS4 via PSN, can I transfer it onto a disc? If I can do that, could I play the movie on my DVD player somehow?

Answer (score 3):

There used to be multiple options to play your Playstation videos on PC *(see edit history)*, but unfortunately Sony has removed support for all of them.

Currently it seems the only way to play them is on PS4/PS5, or on an Android TV using the [Playstation Video app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playstation.video.atv&hl=en_US&gl=US)

Comment: Per the link, Media Go was discontinued in 2018

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes, the video player was discontinued too. I actually worked on both of those apps, so that was especially sad for me :(

Answer (score 0):

No, movies purchased on your PS4 are downloaded to your PS4. They cannot be transferred to a disc by any means.

Answer (score -3):

Uh, actually you can.  What you would need to do is connect the PS4 hard drive to a computer and use software that can access the PS4 file system.  Then you can get the movie into a file, decode it using further software into a DVD-burnable format, and burn away.

This would require you to remove the hard drive from the PS4, most likely.

Comment: "*Downvote these other guys for me, will ya?*" This site doesn't work like that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Connect the PS4 hard drive to a computer and use software that can access the PS4 file system" - *What* software? As far as I'm aware, PS4 harddrives are highly encrypted and require proprietary software in order to view the contents on a PC